# Polymorphic empty relation in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

I run an Alloy command that involves finding witnesses for some existentials, like this one:

```
pred foo { 
  some x, y : E -> E | 
    baz[x,y] || qux[x,y] 
}
```

Alloy comes up with a model where `foo` is true. I look at the model in the Visualizer, and find that `y` happens to be the empty relation. I want to dig deeper into the model and see whether `baz` or `qux` is true. So I fire up the Evaluator window and type `baz[$foo_x, ???]`. But what can I type for `???`? Since `y` is empty, there is no variable with the name `$foo_y`. And typing `none` or `{}` gives a type-checking error.

Does Alloy provide an empty relation that can be used at any type? Or is there any way to get at the `y` witness even though it's empty?

Comment: A workaround that I've been using: `$foo_x - $foo_x` gives me the empty relation at the correct type. But it's quite an ugly hack! Is there a more principled way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive baz[$foo_x, none->none] should work. The relation none has arity 1, and by using cross product you can get empty relations of the desired arity. The explanation for this can be found in the paper "A Type System for Object Models" by Jonathan Edwards, Daniel Jackson and Emina Torlak.

Comment: This worked great; thanks very much. I hadn't twigged that `none` had only a fixed arity. (Though I still think it would be nicer if Alloy were designed to expose the name `$foo_y` even though the corresponding relation is empty.)